# Did the Marshallplan help export the English language?

Tags: american-english

I am currently doing research about the English language and how it is dominating non-English speaking countries (music, movies, etc). I've read some interesting facts and I want your opinion about it with a simple question: did the Marshallplan help export the English language to Europe?

Comment: From a brief study I made of post-war history, the Marshall Aid agreement with France mandated that they had to show in their cinemas a specifically high proportion of Hollywood films. (The Truman Administration (as indeed was the British Foreign office, under Ernest Bevin) was obsessed with the idea that Reds were everywhere. So they wanted the French population to be watching wholesome American produced films, and not "communist propaganda". I suspect this was the case with other European countries, especially Italy.

Comment: This would probably be a good question to ask on the History site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do still have any sources left? I am also thinking that Coca-Cola and such helped export the language.

Comment: Note that it's the "Marshall Plan", not the "Marshalplan".

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: How could it not help? (_everything_ has an effect) So the real question is how much in comparison to the other possible effects. Just the plain presence/invasion/occupation of West European countries by English and American troops probably had more of an effect. What other possible reasons for the popularity of English as a foreign language in Europe have you found?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The on-topic scope doesn't mention anything about social history of English. It would be against all logic to exclude this question as off-topic.

Comment: @Mitch As WS2 says, This would probably be a good question to ask on the History site. (And/or 'linguistics'.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Don't be such a spoilsport. This is a very interesting question and it is at least related to English. Don't you think it is bad for the community if you close tons of questions that are interesting to other people? Don't you agree that bureaucracy and regulations are often hated for good reason?

Comment: @WS2: This is extremely interesting. Do you have any idea about where I could find more information about France's being forced by the Americans to show Hollywood films?

Comment: @Cerberus Don't you think it is bad for the community if you seek to subvert the stated guidelines? Almost everything English people talk about is 'related to English' as it's discussed in that language. And _much_ of it is interesting.  Also, I expect you to address similar anti-democratic comments to Drew, jimm101, FumbleFingers and Josh61....

Comment: ... Wouldn't you think that OP,  who is 'currently doing research about the English language and how it is dominating non-English speaking countries' should have posted some research results? Is a question asking for opinions ever going to be on-topic? Mitch throws this back to OP.

Comment: @Edwin: I did not mean to except you, but a comment can only ping one user. You're talking about rules again, not people, nor content. I know you feel you are doing the right thing, and I think you are very smart and knowledgeable, and I enjoy our discussions about the (non-meta-)content of questions and answers; but too often when I see your name on this site it is about something negative. And why are rules so terribly important anyway? Again, you are absolutely not the only one to do this, but I know it affects my enthusiasm. Even if you're right, perhaps this is something to think about.

Comment: @Cerberus When I suggested on Meta not too long ago that, as I was tired of dismissing all the flak, I was considering ignoring the politico-policing side of ELU, I was told off in no uncertain terms. But I'm the sort of person who sees thin ends of wedges, potential threats to credibility / standards (in answers as well as questions), and non-democratic pressure; perhaps the best thing now is to leave entirely (apart from the occasional dip in to see if JL has further gems). This is not knee-jerk and certainly not pity-me; I've been investing far too much time here. Usually very happily.

Comment: @Cerberus I think I may have read about it in a biography of de Gaulle. But there is sure to be more direct material out there, if not in English, then in French. Just by googling *Marshall Plan + Hollywood + France*, I got [this](https://theses.lib.vt.edu/theses/available/etd-05062006-142739/unrestricted/MarshallFilmThesis.pdf). It is not exactly what you are looking for but perhaps a good lead. Try looking at the author's bibliography.I will keep my eyes open for you.

Comment: @Cerberus The requirement may have been on the French government to remove its restrictions on non-French language films. [This article looks interesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum%E2%80%93Byrnes_agreement)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Allow me to say Edwin, that I think you make an immense contribution to the site. It would be far poorer without you. My only negative remark has been that some of your comments are so abbreviated (obviously for space consideration), that I sometimes find it difficult to pick out the point of what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

As English is spoken in England and England is part of Europe the idea that English was exported to Europe is a bit funny, especially as English is closely related with Frisian, Low German and Scandinavian languages. What is more, half of the English dictionary consists of words of Latin/French vocabulary, and the Latin vocabulary is used in all European languages.

Comment: This "reply", as well as not attempting to answer the question, is wilfully misinterpreting the words used in the question. -1.

Comment: @ColinFine - Do you really think so?

Comment: What @rogermue says here is valid: saying that English was exported from America to Europe does not make sense. However, this was written as an answer and it is not an answer. A comment would have sufficed. Anyway, as Edwin Ashworth pointed out this question belongs in a history forum.

Comment: The question is "Did the Marshallplan help export the English language?" My answer is No, what a funny idea. I didn't use the word No, I think it is self-evident from what I wrote.  And I think "No" is an answer.